# use object3D before actual model is loaded

Tags: typescript, three.js

So I guess Object3D is actually just an transfer object with information and the model geometry + material. Im loading different models in my project. the object3D obj for each model is returned and added to the a container obj and then to the scene and "rendered" before the model is actually loaded, but its not visible yet. As soon as its loaded it appears in the view.

Is this a proper way to do? Im generating different parts, each part has a model, a boxGeometry mesh, can have a fill model and can have a extra model. All parts are grouped in an container obj. Right now im having the problem, that the actual model isnt positioned at all but everything else is.

Should i wait for each model to load before using the object3d obj? I like that it is building up part by part as it gets loaded. Why am I able to compute the bounding box with box3 before its completely loaded?

Comment: there are many ways to answer this question. it depends on your use case.

Comment: I basicly just wanna know if it is bad practice. Im actually able to compute the bounding box though the model is not loaded, because parallel im making boxes with the same size as the model. Everything is working now correctly, but I still feel like, this is may lead to future errors or unthought situations